# What's the 3D equivalent of a 2D rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

In 2 dimensional vector space, a rotation can be described as a rotation around an axis pointing along a third basis vector.

What would the equivalent operation look like in 3 dimensions? i.e. a "rotation" around an "axis" defined by a fourth basis vector?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation for one of several representations of 3D rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in 3D (and only 3D) all rotations can still be described by an (oriented) axis $a$, and the angle of rotation $\theta$ (measured counterclockwise in a plane orthogonal to and oriented consistently with $a$, say) about that axis. This is the so-called *axis-angle* representation of a rotation.

The difference here is that the axis of rotation is just an ordinary vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, unlike in 2D where the "axis of rotation" is a vector pointing out of the plane.

Comment: I don't think I should have used the word rotation in the question - what I'm really asking, is can we invent some new operation on 3D space, which is in some way a generalisation of a rotation in 2D space, and if so what would that look like?

Comment: One way of interpreting your question is a rotation that can take you into any other "rotated configuration". Then, in 3D it would be the composition, or multiplication, of 3 3D axis-angle rotations.

Comment: yes, but what does it look like if you position the rotation axis along a 4th basis vector orthogonal to the 3d basis vectors? Does the geometry remain in 3D, and if so, what does the transformation look like?

Comment: @tonicsoft In 4D there's no such thing as rotating "about an axis." If a linear transformation $T$ of 4D space is an orientation-preserving isometry, and it fixes one axis, it must also fix a second one. This is because $\det T = 1$ and so since $T$ has one eigenvalue of $1$ (with eigenvector the fixed axis), it has at most two complex eigenvalues and at least one other real eigenvalues (which must be $1$ and have a corresponding eigenvector which is fixed/inverted.)

Comment: Thanks @user7530, I believe this is the answer to my question. So, loosely speaking, you can't extend the concept by 1 dimension because 3 is odd but 4 is even?